# Array index out of range. ERROR

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Im fairly new to swift and would like some help on this topic. I am receiving an error saying my array index is out of range. the error is in line 85. I know what the problem is I just dont know how to fix it and Ive spend a few hours just on line 85!! Any help appreciated!!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {


    var hotels = [Hotels]()
    var hotelArray : [[Hotels]] = [];


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    var hotel1 = Hotels(name: "Four Seasons Thailand", image: UIImage(named: "four1")!, rating: "Five Stars")
    var hotel2 = Hotels(name: "Ritz Carlton Dubai ", image: UIImage(named: "ritz2")!, rating: "Five Stars")
    var hotel3 = Hotels(name: "Four Seasons Miami", image: UIImage(named: "four3")!, rating: "Five Stars")
    var hotel4 = Hotels(name: "Beverly Wilshire", image: UIImage(named: "bev4")!, rating: "Five Stars")
    var hotel5 = Hotels(name: "Ritz Carlton Cancun", image: UIImage(named: "ritz5")!, rating: "Five Stars")
    var hotel6 = Hotels(name: "Westin Diplomat", image: UIImage(named: "w1")!, rating: "Four Stars")
    var hotel7 = Hotels(name: "W New Orleans", image: UIImage(named: "w2")!, rating: "Four Stars")
    var hotel8 = Hotels(name: "W Savannah", image: UIImage(named: "w3")!, rating: "Four Stars")
    var hotel9 = Hotels(name: "W Times Square", image: UIImage(named: "w4")!, rating: "Four Stars")
    var hotel10 = Hotels(name: "W Miami", image: UIImage(named: "w5")!, rating: "Four Stars")

    hotelArray = [ [hotel1, hotel2, hotel3, hotel4, hotel4],[hotel6, hotel7, hotel8, hotel9, hotel10] ]


    }



    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return hotelArray.count
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return hotelArray[section].count

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,

        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        // assume that it will be either a header or footer first.
        var reuseIdentifier = "headerId";
        // now check to see if it's the type that we didn't assume it would be.
        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter {
            // reassign the identifier

        }
        // dequeue the reusable view and give it information
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCollReusableCellCollectionReusableView;

        // configure the headerFooter view
        header.headerTitle.text = hotelArray[indexPath.section][0].rating

        header.deleteButton?.tag = indexPath.section;

        // return our view
        return header;
    }





    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //write here
         let cell : CellCollectionCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellReuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellCollectionCollectionViewCell;

       //naming and setting the cells properties here!!
        //cell.myLabel.text = "hello \(indexPath.row) S: \(indexPath.section)";

        cell.myLabel?.text = hotelArray[indexPath.row][0].name;



        // return the cell
        return cell;
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the row as segment. That is of course out of bounds.

```
cell.myLabel?.text = hotelArray[indexPath.row][0].name
```

should be

```
cell.myLabel?.text = hotelArray[indexPath.segment][indexPath.row].name
```

Comment: You are welcome. Think you should flag my answer for the ppl that are looking for the same answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

If I am getting this correctly you have to change this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return hotelArray.count
    }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return hotelArray[section].count

    }
```

to this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return 10

    }
```

Comment: Nikos, thanks for replying. hotelArray is an array of arrays. I have to have two sections and 5 cells in each section and they have to be dynamic so when more hotels get added or more sections get created It would still work. The sections come up fine and the cells are all there but when i try to name the cells in line 85 it says the index is out or range.